# How to extract a whole word from a sentence by a specific fragment in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, text-segmentation

How can I obtain a whole word within a string-type sentence? \

For instance, if the given string was:

```
The app has been updated to 88.0.1234.141 which contains a number of fixes and improvements.
```

And I want to get the word 88.0.1234.141 by a specific fragment "**.0.**"
How can I grab every word that contains "**.0.**"? Is there a fast way to do it maybe like Regex instead of using nested loops?

Comment: string input = "The app has been updated to 88.0.1234.141 which contains a number of fixes and improvements.";
            string pattern = @"[.\d]+\.0\.[.\d]+";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
        string[] indexes = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) to solve this. Therefore you can use a simple approach: Take each word containing `.0.` inside. Each word should be surrounded by a space. The expression which results could look like this:

[image: Visualized regex]

Here is an implemented sample of the expression:

```
string input = "The app has been updated to 88.0.1234.141 which contains a number of fixes and improvements.";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^-\s]*\.0\.[^-\s]*");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

The output will be

> 88.0.1234.141